# Using a function on a variable (column) when plotting with ggplot2/ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Normally when you want to plot a variable vs another, you just supply the variable names and that's all cool. If the variable you want is the result of a computation, you can add that as a column to your data.frame or data.table and then use it. However this creates a lot of junk/redundant data if you have big data frames and need to plot these new columns just once. So I am essentially trying to find a way to use functions on variables instead.

I'll try to illustrate that with an example:

```
data(iris)
ggboxplot(iris, x="Species", y="Sepal.Width", add = "jitter")
```

[image]

Will plot the sepal width for different species of iris flowers. However if you want to a custom function on a variable, e.g:

```
ggboxplot(iris, x=round("Sepal.Length"), y="Sepal.Width", add = "jitter")
Error in round("Sepal.Length") : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

This makes sense, since the function doesn't know that the text in quote refers to a variable.

Note that I have been using the `ggpubr` package for prettier plots, but I think the problem is essentially further down in `ggplot2`

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x=floor(Sepal.Length), y=Sepal.Width)) + geom_boxplot()
Warning message:
Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...)?
```

[image]

One way to bypass this is to override the aes mapping, however this results in a slightly weird x-axis

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(y=Sepal.Width, x=Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(group=floor(Sepal.Length)))
```

[image]

I am thinking there has to be a simpler way to get this done, any advice? I would ideally like to keep using `ggboxplot()` from `ggpubr` package, but if it can't be done there I can consider using the `ggplot2` alone.

Comment: On `ggplot2` at least, the problem (as the error suggests) is that you are trying to plot a continuous x-variable in a boxplot, which takes categorical x. Another way to bypass this is by converting x to a factor: `x = factor(floor(Sepal.Length))`. That is essentially what the group argument is doing, but you don't get the "weird" axis because each integer is a category. Of course, if you don't have sequential integers (e.g. `c(4, 5, 20, 40)`) the axis will not be in scale (numerically-wise, let's say).

Answer (score 0):

To keep using the ggboxplot() function, a possible solution is to create a wrapper custom function around it as follow:

```
 libray(ggpubr)
 ggboxplot2 <- function(data, x, y, ...){
    data[[y]] <- floor(data[[y]])
    ggpubr::ggboxplot(data, x, y, ...)
 }
```

Create the boxplot using the custom function:

```
ggboxplot2(iris, x = "Species", y = "Sepal.Width", add = "jitter")
```

Comment: That would necessitate a new wrapper for each function, or a function that takes another function as a parameter. Also what if I want the function to be applied to x sometimes, and y on other times? Not very flexible in the long run. (PS: i dont want to sound too negative, ggpubr is a great library otherwise thanks a big bunch for it)